# Getting model "identifiableName()" from revisionable

Tags: php, laravel-4, revisionable

In the [revisionable package](https://github.com/VentureCraft/revisionable) it's possible to get the identifiable name of a related model by defining the  `identifiableName()` method on a model, setting the field to display instead of id. E.g. 'name' or 'title'.

Is it possible to do similar with unrelated model. So say I got all revisions for a certain model. E.g.

```
$revisions = Venturecraft\Revisionable\Revision::where('revisionable_type', 'post')->get();
```

How can I get the `identifiableName` of the `post` for which each revision was made?

I can already get the post id with `$revision->revisionable_id` but I can't seem to find a way to get the post name without something like `Post::find($revision->revisionable_id)->name` which is expensive for a large list of revisions.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still having this issue.

I think you may be able to do something like:

```
$revision->revisionable->identifiableName();
```

Works fine for me, just be sure to check that the post hasn't been deleted, otherwise you will be trying to get a property from a non-object.

eg:

```
if($revision->revisionable){
   // Post exists
   $revision->revisionable->identifiableName();
}else{
   // Post doesn't exist
}
```